# How to implement caching of AJAX responses? Like in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, caching

Many people ask how to prevent AJAX caching in IE, but I want to implement this technique in other browsers.
I try to use HTTP headers but it's not work and I'm confused in this. Please help me.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want to prevent caching or force caching?

Comment: @Jasper I want to force caching AJAX. Like in IE.

Comment: I did it! without HTTP headers. I just write AJAX responses in a variable. For example, cache[page] = responseContent;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try to use HTTP headers but it's not work

Well, maybe you didn't implement those headers correctly. Here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) that you may take a look at to better understand caching in HTTP.